# Скликивания контекстной рекламы

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Может кто подскажет есть ли какой-то скрипт или плагин для сайта WordPress который будет блокировать повторный вход на сайт с повторного ip адресса. Дело в том что какойто конкурент запускает бота на скликивание контекстной рекламы и весь бюджет съедает буквально за 10 минут.

Comment: Вас это не спасёт. 1. Обычно скликивание идёт с разных IP и вы только можете отрезать клиентов. 2. Яндекс пытается с таким бороться и не считает часть посещений, похожих на кликфрод. 3. Проверьте настройки рекламы и обратитесь с этим в СП Яндекса

Comment: Попробуйте поставить ограничения по возрасту от 18 до ... Иногда помогает от посещений в инкогнито. И не старайтесь попасть на 1е место, пусть тот самый конкурент там сливает бюджет